# How do I select primary key, list<string> in Entity framework linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table:

```
Id    Name
1    Tiggy
1    Boris
1    Halk
1    Gothmog
2    Stamm
2    Wuuf
```

I want to put it into a collection of `<int id, ienumerable<string name>>`. Is there an easy way to do this using linq?

Comment: make a select, join the table to get all the records with the same id and return the groups after ordering them by name or whatever

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Lookup Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460184.aspx) is exactly what you want.

`var foo = table.ToLookup(e => e.Id, e => e.Name);`

It's accessed by an indexer like a Dictionary, but it returns an `IEnumerable<T>` of your values instead of a single value.  It also doesn't throw an exception if the key cannot be found, it returns an empty `Enumerable<T>` of the type.